# Good service for checking usps addresses?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-applications

Does anyone in the us know of a good service (api) that I can use on a web site to verify the usps address a customer would input? One of the other developers has the code in place but it checks a dvd that we receive in the mail every quarter. We would like to just check this over the web instead so it does not go out of date. We would also like it to format the address as well. If anyone has any good suggestions please let me know. This could obviously be a paid solution. Thanks!

Comment: Why not check with the USPS themselves? They should have a white page which listing if any public webservices they have.

Comment: I _think_ he meant US addresses.

Comment: I will check with them. I also found smartystreets.com but they are pretty spendy. I was just hoping someone on here had some experience with one that they could recommend. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USPS has web services for this.  Check out their [Address Information API](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm).

> Make sure mailing addresses are correct. With each tool, up to five
>   lookups can be processed per request. Additional permission is
>   required to use these Ecommerce APIs.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very specific to a company. You can use the USPS tracking webpage and you have to parse the content on that page or use an API that the USPS provides if there are any. This is specific to a company.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.melissadata.com/address-verification/index.htm

Seems to be a very accurate service although I've never used their API, just the website.